# Express.js - How do I wait a Post method before sending result of a Get method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ionic-framework

Hello I'm using Ionic framework and express to comunicate between my application, a server API, and a javascript game. The game sends some information to the API using XMLHttpRequest and post and my application retrives this information using Http from angular/http.

The post part works well and I'm able to send information to the server, but I'm struggling with the get part . The get method is called every time that my page is refreshed but at this time the game hasn't sent the data, and when it does the get method isn't called again, so I never get the data from the server.

the game send info like that :

```js
function sendFriendToInvite(friend, callback) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3001/sendInvite');
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.send(JSON.stringify({friend: friend}));


    req.addEventListener('load', () => {
        console.log(req.responseText);
        var results = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

        //if(results.error) return console.log(results.error);

        if(callback) callback(results);
    });

    req.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
        console.log('an error occured');
        console.log(e);
    });

}
```

the server get and post method are :

```js
var friendToInvite;

/**Send from the game**/
api.post('/sendInvite', function(req, res) {
    console.log("posts! " + req.body.friend);
    friendToInvite = req.body.friend;
    res.send({message: 'friend reçu'})
});

/**retrive by the application **/
api.get('/sendInvite', function(req, res) {
    console.log("get friend to invite");
//here I need friendToInvite be initialised by the post method before sending the response
    res.json({friend: friendToInvite});
});
```

the application get info like that :

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/sendInvite').pipe(
            map(res => res.json())
            ).subscribe(response => {
                console.log('GET Response:', response);
            });
```

I whant the application retrive data when the game send the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use sockets to communicate between the server and your app.

Another simpler and less efficient option may be to do the GET in an interval function so you can call to the server every X seconds (say 1 minute, for example) to update the data. This implies that your app is constantly calling to the server and I strongly discourage it.

EDIT:

I suggested using sockets because I have used this method occasionally to communicate between server and app but it would also be a good option, if you only need communication from the server to the app and not vice versa, to use push notifications.

Comment: I will try that thank you. You said " if you only need communication from the server to the app and not vice versa" that mean if I whant to send data from the application to the server it will not be possible ?

Comment: I'm honestly not an expert in this field and may have confused some concepts. Push notifications are used to communicate between the server and the app and with sockets I think bi-directional communication is possible, although the normal way to communicate between the app and the server would still be through AJAX requests.